# Como hacer incremental el campo de la ID en phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

estoy intentando crear una base de datos pero no encuentro la forma de que el campo de la ID sea incremental.

Comment: Marcando la casilla AI

Comment: @Mathius has podido solucionarlo con la respuesta propuesta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ve a **Tabla** > **Estructura** > Marca **AI**. Asegúrate de tener "None" en "Default". Tienes aquí la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665571/auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin)